# UIViews with same width in AutoLayout not working

Tags: ios, autolayout

My problem is very simple, but i tried to find a solution and it didn't came out.
I have two views that i wanna position horizontally with the same width, based on the content's width. I am doing everything programmatically, using the visual format language. I've searched about this but i did't find nothing related to two or more views with the same width using AL applied to the holder view.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_firstButton, _secondButton);
NSString *visualFormatString = @"H:|[_firstButton]-5-[_secondButton]|";
NSArray *horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:visualFormatString
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];
[self addConstraints:horizontalConstraint];
```

As a result, i'm having views with different widths and the space specified in the visual format language is not applied, the first view(in the left) is bigger than the second view.

I am executing this piece of code in the layoutSubviews of a view that is going to hold this two buttons. The call to the [super layoutSubviews] is made after the AL code.
I tried to figure it out, but i can't find a solution. I could put a static width, but this would not be good, although it work. Can anyone of the community give me a solution for this problem? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Whaat result does this code give you?

Comment: Sorry, i've put it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string needs to include the fact that the two views should have the same width,

```
"H:|[_firstButton]-5-[_secondButton(==_firstButton)]|"
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks for the help! I didn't thought that this was so simple like that.